# Clarification of the concept of Boson Mediator and 'Mediation' in Physics?

Tags: standard-model, neutrinos, interactions, bosons, carrier-particles

I would like to have a clear concept of Higgs '`mediator`' and that '`mediation`' speak in physics, what you 'swap' a particle with the other and why there would be an alternative possibility dominated by bosons in favor, however, of a more extended model that includes other forms of direct interaction such as between the **neutrino-photon** or between **neutrino-neutrino** that the actual quantum physics rules out due to the fact the neutrino (ever seen, but only calculated indirectly as a decay of the Z boson) has no electric charge.

Standard Model *fermions-bosons* prohibits this type of interaction, but always forces a mediation by a boson and I do not think that the reason is only to be found in the properties of elementary particles
Even the Higgs field is a *level mediation*, but can not be the final one because *Universe Nature* is not a state over, but could be organized with additional classes of matter, energy in addition to the domain of the Higgs field.

In addition to the standard model we have not discovered all the properties of the particles, so why not seriously take the idea to extend the principle of consistency that instead prohibits, in principle, the same phenomenon but with a different description.

Who forbids me to think that the particles are not equipped with a primitive form of identity that arises intelligently to your measurements and you can not behave as a quality?

These are my questions related to the fact that throughout this universe we are still as mere observers. I can not believe only in this mediation, but I prefer to be considered as a limitation of our knowledge and our experience in relation to this intelligence, still unknown and elusive.

Comment: The latter part of your question does not make sense within physics. The "mediator" part can be answered with mathematics . Physics is about mathematical models that fit data and observations and can predict future behavior.

Comment: you're right, though I do not speak of a single boson or law, but the way they organize themselves as a structure, such as intelligence and that's what I want to understand by physical. That is, the fundamental interactions are one of the ways in which physicists have discovered the Higgs field to be so. But I have not figured out how can I interact with it and why he could not describe the same event, but from an interaction that is not a clash inside the detectors. That's all.

Comment: @user3520363-can you explain what you mean by  "Higgs field is a level mediation"-in terms of physics?

Comment: disturbance - excitation of the space that behaves like a virtual particle between 2 or more particles field within which they exchange properties ( spin , momentum ). 
The higgs field does not act as a mediator , that I understood but I think it's just a new and different way of being mediation because maybe change the dimension type and so we would have to also change the way we access the Higgs Field upper level. But mediation is , otherwise we should change our way of seeing the end of boson and review the concept of Hilbert space and the wave function.

Comment: And I think not only the way we view as observers , but also the identity of our being with the phenomenon . Do not just use neutrinos to explore what happens inside the stars , but we also have to change .

Answer (score 1):

> Who forbids me to think that the particles are not equipped with a primitive form of identity that arises intelligently to your measurements and you can not behave as a quality?

"arises  intelligently" is not in the physics domain. It is metaphysics, this assigning intelligence to particles, and there exist such [metaphysical](http://divinecosmos.com/contact-us/privacy-policy/62-the-shift-of-the-ages-chapter-06-the-seth-entity-and-consciousness-units)  "theories"  but their discussion is outside the rules of this board, which is about peer reviewed physics.

At best intelligence origins belong to the attempts to [understand consciousness](https://www.google.gr/search?q=physics%20and%20consciousness&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=mVNSV6XzIvLR8geVj5bADg) as an extension of physics, but it is not mainstream physics.

Comment: I think the limit is thinner than you might believe. And if consciousness is not something measurable directly with the tools ? 
and it is from this 'extension' of matter that depends on the Higgs Field ?

Answer (score 0):

The use of the term mediator in this question appears to refer to gauge bosons. These couple to fermions or other particles that have their coupling charge. In the case of QCD gluons, the gauge particle of force, has color charge and couples to itself.

This Higgs boson or field is not of this nature. The elementary idea is that the Higgs field consists of two doublets $(H^+, H^-)$ and $(H^0, h)$. The weak interactions have the intermediary gauge bosons $W^\pm, Z$. These are massless, and because there is no rest frame to measure their spin they have only transverse field amplitudes. At low energy the $H^\pm$ are absorbed into the $W^\pm$, so we might call these particles Whigs (sounds like the old UK political party), and the $H^0$ is absorbed into the $Z$, call it a Zhing. The degree of freedom in these scalar components are converted into longitudinal components of these gauge particles. This means there is a rest mass to these gauge particles.

The last component in the neutral group is $h$, and this is the Higgs particle that was detected in 2012. This was predicted to have a mass in the range found. The Higgs field is then qualitatively different from a gauge force,

Comment: mmm.. who assures me that the Higgs field is part of a deeper field consists of more subtle interactions still not measurable? Physicists have not yet found all the particles and functions. Are you saying that the Higgs Field is the mediator of himself (higgs boson)? When you say 'quality' mean that there is a new form of mediation? What kind of transformation is then the decay of the Higgs boson into other particles?

Comment: Have you taken any introductory course on quantum field theory and standard model?

Comment: yes, but you can't tell me that Higgs Field is last field. What is beyond?